# What number is n if n-1 is divisible by 15 and n+1 divides 1001?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

Does anyone know how I could solve this problem in my number theory course. I am kind of clueless about it. Got some ideas but none of them gives some concrete answer. I figured out that n is probably 76 but that is just by guessing the answer.

Comment: I know, it was a typo. I corrected it.

Comment: Please edit for clarity and to show your efforts.  It is not clear what you mean by "$n+1$ is contained in $1001$".  If you meant "$n+1$ divides $1001$, say that.

Comment: Note:  since $1001$ has very few divisors, it's a quick search.

Comment: That was the literal translation from my language since I am not 100% sure what they mean by that. But I suppose that it means "n+1 divides 1001". I will correct it.

Comment: I think it's likely that that is what was meant.  In any case, I agree that $76$ is the correct answer (just by searching the divisors of $1001).

Comment: $n=-14$ is also a solution.

Answer (score 0):

$1001=7\cdot 11\cdot 13$, so the divisors of $1001$ are $$n+1\in\{1, 7, 11, 13, \underbrace{77}_{7\cdot 11}, \underbrace{91}_{7\cdot 13}, \underbrace{143}_{11\cdot 13}, 1001\}$$
Removing $2$ to all divisors we have
$$n-1\in\{-1, 5, 9, 11, 75, 89, 141, 999\}$$
Dividing by $15$ we have
$$\frac{n-1}{15}\in\left\{\frac{-1}{15}, \frac{5}{15}, \frac{9}{15}, \frac{11}{15}, 5, \frac{89}{15}, \frac{141}{15}, \frac{999}{15}\right\}$$
The only integer is $5$, so $$\dfrac{n-1}{15}=5\;\Rightarrow\; n=76$$

Comment: $n=76$ is a solution, but it is not the only solution, since $n=-14$ is also a solution.

Comment: Yup, I considered only the positive integers as divisors.

Answer (score 0):

We find in the comments that $76$ is correct. We can identify it without trial and error as follows:

Since $(n+1)|(1001=7×11×13)$, we must have

$n+1=7^a×11^b×13^c$

where $a,b,c\in\{0,1\}$. Evidently $n+1\equiv2\bmod15$ and so must end in $2$ or $7$ base ten. Terminal digit $2$ is impossible for an odd number and terminal digit $7$ requires $a-c=1$ ($3\equiv7^{-1}\bmod10$). So $a=1,c=0$. To get $b$ we add the condition $n+1\equiv2\bmod3$, implied by the $\bmod15$ residue, forcing $b=1$.

Thereby $n+1=77$ and the answer follows.

Comment: I don't understand based on what are we concluding that $a-c=1$? What is the logic behind that reasoning?

Comment: The terminal digit is congruent to $7^a3^c=7^{a-c}$ because of $3×7\equiv1\bmod10$.

Comment: Is no one reading that I first require $a,b,c\in\{0,1\}$?

Comment: Yes that does invalidate my last comment. However I am still not convinced--what if $a=b=0$ and $c=1$. Then $n+1=13 \not = 2 \pmod{15}$.

Comment: $(a-c)\not=-1$.

Answer (score 0):

$n-1=15N\Rightarrow n-1\equiv 0\space\text { or } 5\pmod{10}\Rightarrow n\equiv 1\space\text { or } 6\pmod{10}$.

$n+1$ is not even because it is a factor of $1001$. Then $n$ should be even so $n=10k+6$ and $n+1=10k+7$. Since the divisors of $1001$ are $1,7,11,13,77,91,143,1001$ the only possibilities are $n+1=7$ and $n+1=77$.

Thus $\color{red}{n=76}$